Subject and particle in 彼は来ると思う
In English, we could say "I think he will come" using the pronoun "I", but in Japanese it's omitted. I know it's not common, but if 私 is being omitted, what particle should be there, は or が? If it's は, is は in 彼は making a contrast?

You can say 私は彼は来ると思う. In this case, 彼は来る is an independent sentence within a quote marked with と, so you don't have to worry about the "one は per sentence" rule. Both 私は and 彼は can be contrastive depending on the previous context, but when there's no context, they are just plain topics.
私が彼は来ると思う is still a grammatical sentence, but it would mean "It is me who think he will come", because this が would be taken as an exhaustive-listing particle.
